# andengine lwp extension issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine, live-wallpaper

In andengine lwp extension there is an issue with texture reloading while rotating device or when you come back to homescreen from application. Because of texture reloading it takes some time (~0.5 sec) to get back to normal view, and before it picture is stretched. It is because of texture reloading every time onResume() is called. I tried to avoid it, and call reloading only when switching from preview mode and vice verca. But now i got some bug with texture reloading. Better I'll show it on screenshot.

### Normal

[image]

### Bug

[image]

And this is from logcat when bug happens:

```
11-06 14:49:09.462: E/SurfaceTexture(91): [ru.sergey.abadzhev.nlwlwp.WallpaperActivity] query: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!

11-06 14:49:09.462: E/SurfaceTexture(91): [ru.sergey.abadzhev.nlwlwp.WallpaperActivity] query: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!

11-06 14:49:09.462: E/SurfaceTexture(91): [ru.sergey.abadzhev.nlwlwp.WallpaperActivity] queueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!

11-06 14:49:09.462: E/SurfaceTextureClient(3941): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19

11-06 14:49:09.462: E/(3941): void __egl_platform_queue_buffer(mali_base_ctx_type*, egl_buffer*):845 [EGL-ERROR] unable to queue buffer (0x1c266bc)
```

Any ideas what happens? Or may be somebody will be so greatfull and share lwp extension without bug and reloading textures on rotating device.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A tips is to add the screenshots to the question instead of linking external sites.

Comment: i can't add images before i get 10 reputation(

Comment: Oh, I actually did not remember that. I could have added them if my company had let me access the site they were on. Think it's fixed now anyway. :-)